# calibration with python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the following code to find the corners in the chess board
but when i run it i got nothing no images are shown
and nothing shows that the corners had been found although in the page of opencv they say that an image should appear.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for fname in images:
img = cv2.imread(fname)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find the chess board corners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)

# If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)

    corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners2)

    # Draw and display the corners
    img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2,ret)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's the board image I'm using:

[image: Board image]

Answer (score 0):

The program you gave only display something if the corners have been found.

First, check that the image has successfully been loaded, by adding `cv2.imshow('img',img)` just after `img = cv2.imread(fname)`.

Second, it could be that the corners are not detected in the image you are using (which sometimes happen). Try the same program with simple images, where the chessboard is clearly visible in the center of the image.

Comment: i checked that the image had been loaded and i tried with other images but still have the same result!!

Comment: Can you add the image you are using in your question ?

Comment: Ok, you should have a look at the OpenCV calibration tutorials (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#cameracalibrationopencv). There is no sense in trying to do calibration using the raw chessboard image. Basically, you need to print the chessboard image, stick it on a wood piece, and observe it using a camera in order to calibrate that camera.

Comment: now i'm really confused.
what i want to do is to detect objects using  tow webcams
so that i can calculate the distance between the detected object and the webcams.
so from where should i start?
what are all the things that i need?
i'll be thankful for your help

Comment: Then what you want to do is "stereo 3D reconstruction", for which there should be tons of tutorials on the internet.

Comment: exactly
and because of tons of tutorials on the net i didn't know from where to start

Comment: Well, calibration of your two cameras is a good place to start with, so you should definitely read and reproduce the calibration tutorial I mentionned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //int numBoards = atoi(argv[1]);
    //int board_w = atoi(argv[2]);
    //int board_h = atoi(argv[3]);

    int numBoards =50; // number of different poses
    int board_w =122;   // number of horizontal corners
    int board_h =154;   // number of vertical corners


    Size board_sz = Size(board_w, board_h);
    int board_n = board_w*board_h;

    vector<vector<Point3f> > object_points;
    vector<vector<Point2f> > image_points;
    vector<Point2f> corners;

    vector<Point3f> obj;
    for (int j=0; j<board_n; j++)
    {
        obj.push_back(Point3f(j/board_w, j%board_w, 0.0f));
    }

    Mat img, gray;
    VideoCapture cap = VideoCapture(0); //change to laptop on built web cam

    int success = 0;
    int k = 0;
    bool found = false;
    while (success < numBoards)
    {
        cap >> img;
        cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        found = findChessboardCorners(gray, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

        if (found)
        {
            cornerSubPix(gray, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray, board_sz, corners, found);
        }

        imshow("image", img);
        imshow("corners", gray);

        k = waitKey(1);
        if (found)
        {
            k = waitKey(0);
        }
        if (k == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (k == ' ' && found !=0)
        {
            image_points.push_back(corners);
            object_points.push_back(obj);
            printf ("Corners stored\n");
            success++;

            if (success >= numBoards)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    destroyAllWindows();
    printf("Starting calibration\n");
    Mat intrinsic = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
    Mat distcoeffs;
    vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;

    intrinsic.at<float>(0, 0) = 1;
    intrinsic.at<float>(1, 1) = 1;

    calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, img.size(), intrinsic, distcoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

    FileStorage fs1("/Users/venushka/Desktop/2015/mycalib.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs1 << "CM1" << intrinsic;
    fs1 << "D1" << distcoeffs;

    printf("calibration done\n");

    Mat imgU;
    while(1)
    {
        cap >> img;
        undistort(img, imgU, intrinsic, distcoeffs);

        imshow("image", img);
        imshow("undistort", imgU);

        k = waitKey(5);
        if (k == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cap.release();
    return(0);
}
```

Try This code

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is because of that the line images = glob.glob('*.jpg') can't find the images. put it manually and check. For example:
img = cv2.imread('left12.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the code line

```
cv2.waitKey(500)
```

So even if you find the corners you won't realy see something, because this line only waits for 500 milliseconds until the window gets closed by

```
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So replace 500 with zero and the window will remain open until you focus on it an klick a key on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

as i seen in the chessboard there is (7,7) corners but you put (7,6) in program

change this>> (7,6)

to this >> (7,7)

Comment: Consider adding a code snippet so the OP can be sure where to put these edits.