# camera calibration using python

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to calibrate my tow webcams using the chessboard method 
but each time i excute the code source which is provided in opencv samples
i got this message:

```
processing ../cpp\img1.jpg... chessboard not found
processing ../cpp\img2.jpg... chessboard not found
processing ../cpp\img3.jpg... chessboard not found
processing ../cpp\img4.jpg... chessboard not found
processing ../cpp\img5.jpg... chessboard not found
```

here is the img1
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/04b4U.jpg

okay,the code is the one in opencv samples here it is the part of cv2.FindChessboard()

```
 for fn in img_names:
    print 'processing %s...' % fn,
    img = cv2.imread(fn, 0)
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, pattern_size)
    if found:
        term = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 30, 0.1 )
        cv2.cornerSubPix(img, corners, (5, 5), (-1, -1), term)
    if debug_dir:
        vis = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(vis, pattern_size, corners, found)
        path, name, ext = splitfn(fn)
        cv2.imwrite('%s/%s_chess.bmp' % (debug_dir, name), vis)
    if not found:
        print 'chessboard not found'
        continue
    img_points.append(corners.reshape(-1, 2))
    obj_points.append(pattern_points)

    print 'ok'
```

Comment: You need to show your code. If you don't show it, we can't possibly know what's wrong with it. *Unless* we are psychics, in which case we wouldn't be spending time on SO.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940979/calibration-with-python-and-opencv) post by you related?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is OK, you might have a problem with your chessboard. Have a look at the documentation on function `findChessboardCorners` ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners)), at the end there is a note saying the following:

> The function requires white space (like a square-thick border, the
>   wider the better) around the board to make the detection more robust
>   in various environments. Otherwise, if there is no border and the
>   background is dark, the outer black squares cannot be segmented
>   properly and so the square grouping and ordering algorithm fails.

If you look at the images provided in [this calibration tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#cameracalibrationopencv), **there is a lot more white space around the chessboard and this is important**:

[image]

Also, it might be an impression, but it seems your outer squares do not have the same size than the others, which could also be important.

Comment: @AldurDisciole that's true the outer squares do not have the same size  than the others,i tried it with other pictures taken in concederation the notes above but still have the same problem besides in the pictures used in the opencv don't have to much wite space around the board

Comment: @Sabrine Ok, then the next step is for you to show some code, especially the call to `FindChessboardCorners` and the pattern size you specify.

Comment: @Sabrine So you did not adapted your pattern size from `(9,6)` to `(7,5)`, eventhough your chessboard does not have the same size than the one used in the OpenCV tutorial ?

Comment: Ops! yep i forget this one now it's okay thank you
one more question please, i should do the same thing for the second cam?

Comment: @Sabrine If you use the same chessboard, yes :)

Comment: @AlderDisciple yes, I do
Would you tell me the next step please (i'm working in the stereo 3D reconstruction) and want to measere the distence of an object using 2 webcams

Comment: @Sabrine have a look at the `stereo_match.py` sample in OpenCV and ask a new question if you have troubles.

Comment: Hi again, i tried the stereo_mutch.py and I've change the pictures with an other snapshots taken by my webcams one by the left other by the right but i couldn't really understand the function of this code and the aim